# Butterworth Filter at high Frequencies

Tags: frequency, butterworth

So I have this signal sampled at 300 Hz to begin with and this is the frequency domain:
[image: Original Signal Time Domain]

[image: Original Signal Freq Domain]

I apply a second order butterworth filter using scipy  with a cutoff frequency of 12.6 Hz and this is the resultant signal in time and frequency domains:

```
sos = signal.butter(2, 12.6, 'low', fs=300, output='sos')
x_filt = signal.sosfiltfilt(sos, x)
```

[image: Filtered Signal Time Domain]
[image: Filtered Signal Freq Domain]

My question is shouldn't those frequencies around 300 Hz be filtered out and appear as zero and why aren't they? Should I be using a higher order filter in order to filter out those higher frequencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sampled your signal at 300Hz.

That means your range of valid frequencies (for a real-valued signal) is -150Hz to +150Hz.

When you take the FFT, as you have done, the top half of the spectrum is really from -150Hz to 0$^-$Hz (the bin just before 0 frequency).

Use `numpy.fft.fftshift` to center the 0 frequency bin in the middle of your plots.

Comment: Could you help me explain why there is still high frequency components in the filtered signal?

Comment: @MichaelPozzi There aren't. Rather, once the signal is sampled, the spectrum is repeated to infinity in both directions.  Once it's sampled at 300Hz, you can only see -150Hz to +150Hz (and any aliases if the original unsampled signal had frequency components higher than 150Hz).